# Prevent Windows Explorer from "owning" a directory while viewing it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, cygwin, make

I am running some GNU `make` makefiles via Cygwin, and one of the targets tries to rename a directory:

```
clear_dirs:
    @echo "Creating clean local test directories..."
    @if [ -d $(TESTDIR_IN) ]; then mv -f $(TESTDIR_IN) $(TESTDIR_IN)_OLD; fi
```

This works fine (!) unless I have Windows Explorer open and viewing `$(TESTDIR_IN)`. In that case I get "Permission denied" error, and the `make` fails.

How do I prevent Windows Explorer from causing such problems? I don't remember it doing this before.

Strange thing is: even after navigating to a completely different directory, but in the same Windows Explorer instance, doesn't help - the only thing that helps is closing Windows Explorer.

Edit:

Sysinternals/Autorun/Explorer list:

[image: Sysinternals/Autorun/Explorer]

Comment: You remember incorrectly .A file or directory that is in use cannot be moved.

Comment: Is it really "in use"? Just viewing it's contents in Windows Explorer. I am pretty sure I never had such problems before.

Comment: Explorer has the directory open so you can view the contents

Comment: I've added some more info to the question.

Comment: Have you installed a shell extension lately? Those extensions run inside Windows Explorer and can keep directory handles open. Or is the directory to-be-deleted somehow special (e.g. a git repo) with installed TortoiseGIT shell-ext?

Comment: @Robert Interesting observation. Yes, this directory is located within a Git repository, even the directory itself isn't under source control. I'm not using TortoiseGIT (using SourceTree). I will try to see which, if any, extensions are installed. Not sure how to find out...

Comment: @Robert Please see related: https://superuser.com/questions/1591162/how-to-find-out-which-windows-explorer-extensions-are-installed-and-running

Comment: I've added a screenshot: is there anything suspicious there?